# Intellij IDEA can't generate WSDL from JAVA

Tags: java, soap, intellij-idea, wsdl

I'm trying to generate wsdl from java class in Intellij IDEA.
But i get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis.wsdl.Java2WSDL
```

Could anyone help me solve this issue please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Axis jars should be in classpath. Could you please check that. If this is a maven project, add a maven dependency else, add the jar location in your classpath.